# Foreach inside foreach not working in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to apply foreach inside foreach in knockout but it's not working outer foreach is working fine for me but for inner foreach is it saying `MyFMnu1 is undefined`.

If i put this inner foreach outside then it is working but why it is not working inside the foreach.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: MyFmnu">
      <!-- ko if: key === 'ASM' -->
           <input type="checkbox" value="ASM"  class="styled"  
               name="fldMenuCheck_Acc1" id="fldMenuCheck_Acc1"
               style="width:10%;"/>
      <!-- /ko -->
      <div data-bind="foreach: MyFmnu1">
           <!-- ko if: key === 'ASMS' -->
                <input type="checkbox" value="ASMS"  class="styled"  
                     name="fldMenuCheck_Acc12" id="fldMenuCheck_Acc12"
                     style="width:10%;"/>
           <!-- /ko -->
       </div>
</div>
```

My view model

```
var AccountsViewModel = function () {

    var self = this;

    self.myfavmenu = ko.observable();
    self.PerLzdmenuList = ko.observable();
    self.MyPerlzdMenus = ko.observable();

    self.myfavmenuOtherCount = ko.observable();
    self.MyFmnu = ko.observableArray([]);
};
```

Comment: can you post your view model?

Comment: Show your full HTML markup. I only see 1 `foreach` here.

Comment: Could you show us MyFmnu?  Unless you have a property on the MyFmnu object called MyFmnu1, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside foreach binding the binding context is item of collection, not the root view model.
To get access to parent context in foreach binding use $parent, like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: MyFmnu">
      <!-- ko if: key === 'ASM' -->
           <input type="checkbox" value="ASM"  class="styled"  
               name="fldMenuCheck_Acc1" id="fldMenuCheck_Acc1"
               style="width:10%;"/>
      <!-- /ko -->
      <div data-bind="foreach: $parent.MyFmnu1">
           <!-- ko if: key === 'ASMS' -->
                <input type="checkbox" value="ASMS"  class="styled"  
                     name="fldMenuCheck_Acc12" id="fldMenuCheck_Acc12"
                     style="width:10%;"/>
           <!-- /ko -->
       </div>
</div>
```

more info here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: It works for me . Thanks but hangs sometime when there is large data in loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `MyFmnu1` array as a property for each object in the `MyFmnu` array, it will work.